# Exception has occurred: SSLError HTTPSConnectionPool

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-3.9

**Cod**

```
import requests
irancell='https://shop.irancell.ir/charge/fa/'
mci='https://shop.mci.ir/charge'
Page_Url=requests.get(irancell)
print('Irancell',Page_Url)
Page_Url1=requests.get(mci)
print('mci',Page_Url1)
```

**ERROR**

I encountered this problem in line 6,

```
Exception has occurred: SSLError HTTPSConnectionPool(host='shop.mci.ir', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /charge (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1123)')))
```

of course I have to say that when the site works properly
<Response[500]> Indicates.

500:Internal Server Error:
A generic error message, given when an unexpected condition was encountered and no more specific message is suitable

Please tell me

Answer (score 0):

That's not a problem from your program, The site itself doesn't work. Try opening https://shop.mci.ir/charge from the browser

Comment: Why do you think the site comes down after requesting?
What do you think is causing this problem?

Comment: That's a broad question. There's no single solution for this issue.